# -Wstrict-overflow warning in a function definition

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

How it is possible to get a "assuming no signed overflow" warning for a function definition?

```
warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when assuming that 
                           (X + c) < X is always false [-Wstrict-overflow]
unsigned int index(const ItemRequest& request)
             ^
```

The function body can be found [here](https://paste.kde.org/p4klncyi1).

It seems strange because the return values are only ushort or uint.

Comment: Perhaps there is something *inside* the function that causes the problem? Like when producing the return value. But we cannot tell here.

Comment: @BoPersson no, all the return values are ushort or uint

Comment: Include the body of the funciton / function call in the question, as it's part of the question.

Comment: @Dutow I do not believe that a 250 lines function is appropriate here

Comment: But without the body, we can only tell that the overflow is inside there somewhere - which you probably already realized.

Comment: @Dutow I have done it

Comment: @Zhigalin: The proper warning for that would be "function too big". Really, we're not going to debug something that huge. Refactor that code till you've narrowed it down to 10 lines max, then post those - if it hasn't become obvious yet.

Comment: @MSalters I have said it. Citation: "I do not believe that a 250 lines function is appropriate here – Zhigalin 4 hours ago". I am also not going to debug something that huge just because of 1 warning. I have posted this question because I was wondering why the compiler gives me that warning in such an inappropriate place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function *definition* includes the body of the function. And the body can obviously contain a signed overflow.

The part that you show contains neither a `;` nor a `{` after the argument list, so it's incomplete anyway.

You may get an error where the compiler has problems locating the exact location of the diagnostic. This is especially common when the diagnostic is caused by the optimizer which is working on code that's already gone through quite a few transforms.

Comment: How I can inspect it deeper?